# Need assistance cURL'ing a link

Tags: php, html, curl

I am trying to curl the following link:
http://soundstreamradio.serverroom.net:7424/currentsong?sid=1

It's just a page that displays plain text. This is the cURL PHP code I'm using:

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0';

    $options = array(

        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  =>"GET",        //set request type post or get
        CURLOPT_POST           =>false,        //set to GET
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $user_agent, //set user agent
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie file
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie jar
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
```

And this is what I'm using to call the script:

```
    $result = get_web_page("http://soundstreamradio.serverroom.net:7424/index.html?sid=1");
    if ( $result['errno'] != 0 )
        echo "... error: bad url, timeout, redirect loop ...";
    if ( $result['http_code'] != 200 )
        echo"... error: no page, no permissions, no service ...";
    $page = $result['content'];
```

Now after uploading this to my server and running it, the page just hangs and does nothing, then after the 120 seconds it times out finally displaying all of the error messages (... error: bad url, timeout, redirect loop ..., ... error: no page, no permissions, no service ...)

I'm looking to see if there are any options I can take to pull the data off of this website without the cross domain issues.

Comment: even in browser, its just plain text. fyi: `file_get_contents` works just fine. same as visiting it on a browser

Comment: Shoutcast servers Vary: on the user agent. If you were to get the actual stream, then curl would simply pull heaps of binary data. There's no HTTP response header, just an embedded ICY line. Would be around 1.9MiB after 120secs.

Comment: What I am thinking, is trying to find a way to capture UTF-8 strings, because apparently that is what the page outputs...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo file_get_contents("http://soundstreamradio.serverroom.net:7424/currentsong?sid=1");
```

Use curl_exec and other functions for https connections

Comment: I just tried this, and it just hangs there on the page and times out :(

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me - plain and simple

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://soundstreamradio.serverroom.net:7424/currentsong?sid=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

this also works

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://soundstreamradio.serverroom.net/currentsong?sid=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PORT , 7424);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

if neither of these work then I would suggest looking at your firewall as you are probaly being blocked on port 7424